# Pig Latin Sentence Translator (Sentence)

Tags: java

So I am having trouble figuring out how I should go about doing this, I have the code to translate a word into Pig Latin, but currently I cannot think of how to apply that to a whole sentence. I started to try and use a while loop to loop through each of the words, but after a bit that hit a dead end, and now I don't know where to go with this.

Below is my work to get a word "translated" into Pig Latin.

```
public static String toPigLatin (String original_word)
{
    int first_vowel = firstVowelIndex(original_word);

    if (first_vowel == -1)
    {
        return original_word;
    }
    else if (first_vowel == 0)
    {
        return original_word + "way";
    }
    else 
    {
        return original_word.substring(first_vowel) + original_word.substring(0, first_vowel) + "ay";
    }

}
```

Comment: are you running into a specific issue? How about using [string#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to separate your words into a string array and just iterate through that array?

Comment: Is your `firstVowelIndex` correct?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to really get on track. I was thinking something like that since I have done similar things in other languaes, but I am in a Intro to Java class and we haven't got there yet.

Comment: Yes, all the code above is correct, but that only changes a word, not a whole sentence. So I was thinking of using this method and then iterating it to change the words in the sentence, but I can't get thinking on how to do that right now.